# javascript onClick() function pass Variable for img src= to another page

Tags: javascript, onclick

I want to pass a variable which holds an img src to another page using javascript onClick() function. How can I do it either by **id** or by **name** tag.
Here's What I'm looking for:

Get the **img src** variable by onclick() from home.html & pass to & document.write() to img.html using a `location.href = '/image';` in my function()

Thanks in advance.

**function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function img(id)
{
    this.id = id;
    var i = document.getElementById("image").src;
    var j = new Image();
    j.src = i;
    document.body.appendChild(j);
    document.write('"<img src="' + j + '"' + '/>');
}

</script>
```

**home.html**

```
<div class="container">

    <ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span3">
    <img src="../img/google-app-engine.gif" class="thumbnail" id="abc" name="a">
    <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="">
<button class="btn btn-inverse" type="button" onclick="img();">Share</button>
    </li>
    <li class="span3">
    <img src="../img/google-app-engine.gif" class="thumbnail" id="xyz" name="b">
    <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="">
<button class="btn btn-inverse" type="button" onclick="img();">Share</button>
    </li>
    <li class="span3">
    <img src="../img/google-app-engine.gif" class="thumbnail" id="zzz" name="c">
    <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="">
<button class="btn btn-inverse" type="button" onclick="img();">Share</button>
    </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

The Page I want to pass the img src value to is

**img.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="image" name="image">
    <img src="" id="image" name="image"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a hidden input field?

Comment: You can not have duplicate id's. And you can not have an id that starts with a Number.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do here? Do you want to open img.html with the clicked image, or are you just sending it to the html page and aiming to use the response for something?

Comment: Why do you have that document.write there? You're already adding the image to the body..

Comment: can you modify the img.html page?

Comment: @Susanoh13 yeah something like it.. I want to send the image from **home.html** when onclicked() button is clicked to **image.html page** so I can do some stuffs ..

Comment: what you need inthe second(img.html) page? the source and the id? ps: in htmlthe id of an element should not start with a number, but every browser supports it for what i know. it shouldbe named (id="img1")

Comment: @cocco what do you mean by modify? sorry I didn't get that. I'm just looking to **send an image from one page to another.**

Comment: can you also add javascript to the second page?

Comment: @cocco hmm, ok sorry i didn't know about id thing, not a problem, id can be an alphabet

Comment: @cocco yes I can add js to 2nd pg if needed.

Comment: ok.. thats a start and what about browser support? you need that also ie6 supports that? or it's enough ifthe modern browser supports it? like ie10 safari chrome IOS android

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum hmm, not much experience in js. a bit noob.

Comment: Then start with the basics, read the MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) introduction to JS tutorial (it's free!) or Eloquent JavaScript (another free book!) http://www.codecademy.com/ also have free tutorials. Your comments indicate you lack the basic understanding to actually solve the problem at hand. Coding this way is painful and unrewarding - JS is a great language and you can enjoy it - don't put yourself in this position.

Comment: and what about browser support?ie10 safari chrome IOS android opera enough?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum hmm thanks for the advice, I've completed js from [link](http://codecademy.com) && have got the basic understanding of function arrays & objects, so I've started to write my own code, where I'm looking to get some help...

Comment: @cocco all would be good, however I'm just looking to achieve the functionality of passing the img from one page to another

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**OLD school way**

i don't know exactly but i think this is also supported by the ie6;

i only added the necessary code

*home.html*

```
<html>
<head>
<title>thumbs</title>
<script>
function sendimg(a){
 window.location.href='b.html#id='+a.id+'&src='+a.src;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="imgs/img1.jpg" id="img1" onClick="sendimg(this);">
<img src="imgs/img2.jpg" id="img2" onClick="sendimg(this);">
<img src="imgs/img3.jpg" id="img3" onClick="sendimg(this);">
</body>
</html>
```

*img.html*

```
<html>
<head>
<title>img</title>
<script>
function getimg(){
 var a=window.location.href.split('#')[1].split('&'),
 id=a[0].split('=')[1],
 src=a[1].split('=')[1],
 img=document.images[0];
 img.id=id;
 img.src=src;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="getimg()">
<img src="ablankimage.gif">
</body>
</html>
```

now give me some seconds and i write the modern way.

**Modern way**

.. so this example has less support but can do alot more.
i also wrote some similar things in a different way and added some special modern features you can look after as you said your new to javascript.

home.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>thumbs</title>
<script>
(function(W){
 function init(){
  W.document.getElementById('thumbs').addEventListener('click',sendimg,false);
 }
 function sendimg(e){
  var a=e.target;
  if(a.parentNode.id=='thumbs'){
   W.localStorage['imginfo']=JSON.stringify({src:a.src,id:a.id});
   W.location.href="img.html";
  }
 }
 W.addEventListener('load',init,false)
})(window)
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="thumbs">
<img src="imgs/img1.jpg" id="img1">
<img src="imgs/img2.jpg" id="img2">
<img src="imgs/img3.jpg" id="img3">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

img.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>img</title>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
 var img=document.createElement('img');
 var info=JSON.parse(window.localStorage['imginfo']);
 delete window.localStorage['imginfo'];
 img.src=info.src;
 img.id=info.id;
 document.body.appendChild(img);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

if you wan't me to explain something morejust ask ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code, both of them works good, how can I load the **img** inside a desired **<div> container** on the **img.html** page?

Comment: looking at your example you can't ... they have the same id and that is wrong. the div should have id="imgContainer" and the image should be removed .. then use document.getElementById('imgContainer').appendChild(img), this is for the second code.

Answer (score 0):

there can be a way to make this Morden way to walk on all images which are in one table of the database?i used to try that but it's used only on the first image.then i tried to put that morden way in php pages.

here's my php pages:

```html
*home.php:

              <?php
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=imagetest', 'root', '');
 
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>thumbs</title>

</head>
<body>
 <div >
<?php
 $req = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY idimage DESC  ");

 
   while ($donnees = $req->fetch()): 
    ?>
    <div id="thumbs"><?php echo ('<img  style="width:180px;height:180px;margin-left:40%;" src = "'.$donnees['lien'].'">');?> </div>


     <script>
      (function(W){
       function init(){
        W.document.getElementById('thumbs').addEventListener('click',sendimg,false);
       }
       function sendimg(e){
        var a=e.target;
        if(a.parentNode.id=='thumbs'){
         W.localStorage['imginfo']=JSON.stringify({src:a.src,id:a.id});
         W.location.href="img.php";
        }
       }
       W.addEventListener('load',init,false)
      })(window)
      </script>
    
  <?php endwhile; ?>
     
    </div> 
<body>
</body>
</html>

*img.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>img</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style type="text/css">
 img{height: 300px;width: 400px;}
</style>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
 var img=document.createElement('img');
 var info=JSON.parse(window.localStorage['imginfo']);
 delete window.localStorage['imginfo'];
 img.src=info.src;
 img.id=info.id;
 document.body.appendChild(img);
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -5):

This would easily be done with Ajax + PHP + jQuery

**JQUERY**

```
var link = $("img").attr("src");

    $.ajax{
       url: "img.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: {"img":link},
       success: function(e){
        // Whatever you want
       }
    }
```

**PHP**

```
       <?php
     if (isset($_POST['img'])){
     $link = $_POST['img']
    }

   // Whatever you want to do with the variable $link
    ?>
```

I don't know if this is going to solve your problem, hope it does.

Comment: What if the page the OP is referring to is a new page, that isn't loaded with AJAX?

Comment: The OP does not mention any server-side code. He is also using raw html files, not php.